# Is it possible to undo a :bdelete in Vim?

Tags: vim, buffer, undo

I've gotten used to `Ctrl-Shift-T` in Firefox to undo the closing of a tab, is it possible to get similar functionality in Vim? Googling didn't point me towards anything useful for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not aware of an existing solution but it seems relatively easy to save the name of the deleted buffer in a variable on `BufDelete` and define a simple mapping that uses that variable. Let's see...

```
autocmd BufDelete * let g:latest_deleted_buffer = expand("<afile>:p")

nnoremap <F6> :e <C-R>=fnameescape(g:latest_deleted_buffer)<CR><CR>
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about the BufDelete event (and my vimscript-fu is weak anyway). Is it possible to make this into a `:` command instead of a normal mode map?

Comment: This works perfectly in Cygwin, but in Windows gVim, after adding the given `autocmd` I'm getting an error `E18: Unexpected characters in :let` whenever I do a `:bd`. I'm guessing it's the backslash characters in Windows paths. Could you please suggest a way around that?

Comment: Ok, I figured out the second issue, changing the expand command to `expand("<afile>:p:gs?\\?/?")` fixes that problem. This undo works perfectly now, thanks a lot!

Comment: Sorry, I was AFK for the night. My solution assumed UNIX because you didn't say much about your environment. I'm happy this simple solution works for you.

Comment: Dashes are not allowed in variable names, that causes the E18. Also, you should probably expand to a full path `<afile>:p` to handle changes of CWD, and use `fnameescape()` in the mapping.

Comment: @IngoKarkat, answer edited as per your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify, `:bdelete` in VIM is used to delete buffers (buffer delete). I am not aware of any way of 'undoing' it, however, maybe the following will help you:

I have a file on my desktop called `test.rtf`

If I use the following command in the terminal: `vim test.rtf` followed by: `:bdelete` + `Enter` - it opens up a blank screen ready to type into. If you type in: `:q` followed by `Enter` to quit, you aren't saving any changes, so you are effectively undoing the mistake.

I hope this may be somewhat helpful.

Comment: It seems to me that you're assuming `:bdelete` empties the contents of the currently-open file or something, but it actually simply closes the file, so I'm not looking for ways to undo any changes made (and `:q` wouldn't do that anyway, we'd need either `:q!` or better `:e!`). What I'm looking for is a simple shortcut to avoid the bother of having to type `:e ` followed by the whole path of the just-closed file when I wish to reopen it immediately.